# Why isn't the clickable Google Maps search on the webView page?

Tags: ios, swift

Problem: The iOS App have a webView window, where the form is located. In this window connected Google maps, and realtime-search for places / addresses. When you write text, the search works, finds places, but it is not clickable.

The most interesting: in android app, and with normal browsers (even safari) everything works well. Tell me how to fix the situation, or how to fix this error, or at least where to dig ...

p.s. There is also an error only with the iOS app here: the cursor does not blink when the input is active.